# Change permssion of all perl programs in unix

Tags: bash, unix, find, sh, chmod

I need to use command substitution, providing the command to change the permissions of all Perl programs with extensions .pl to 755. 
When I try to use the command:

```
chmod 755 `find $HOME -name "*.pl"`
```

I get

```
chmod: missing operand after ‘755’
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That means that you executed `chmod 755`, which means `find $HOME -name "*.pl"` didn't return anything.

---

Note that the following are better because they don't risk running afoul of the limit on the length of the command line, and they handle shell metacharacters (such as spaces) in the value of `$HOME` and in the paths returned by `find`:

```
find "$HOME" -name "*.pl" -exec chmod 755 {} +         # GNU find required.
find "$HOME" -name "*.pl" | xargs -r chmod 755         # Doesn't support LF in file names.
find "$HOME" -name "*.pl" -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 755
```